# Where is the "I don't carry a gun. I drive," clip from Drive (2011)?

Tags: drive

During the trailer the Driver says, "I don't carry a gun. I just drive," but it's missing from the film. Maybe I'm missing it.

Comment: FYI, trailer scenes are often cut from the final movie.

Comment: @cde Looks like in this case OP just missed the scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! It's around time ~49:00, when he makes the deal to help Standard :)